# Getting fatal: error when closing sha1 file: Permission denied fatal: unpack-objects failed in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-git-plugin

We are receiving below issue with git in Jenkins pipeline job

```
fatal: error when closing sha1 file: Permission denied
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

This is happening only with one specific branch and branches created out of that branch

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to check the write permissions for Jenkins user on the folder.

Comment: We resolved it, it was due to Git client version installed in Jenkins